# How to listen or check whatsapp icoming calls through notifications?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, native, whatsapp

I am creating an app that will announce the incoming caller name and number through notifications, I've created this for phone but now i want to add one more feature that whenever user will get a call through whatsapp app should also announce caller name and number. but i don't know how to access the incoming caller notification. I've tried to access through broadcast listener and notificationlistener but unable to do it. please help me out . Thanks

I've tried to access through broadcast listener and notificationlistener but unable to do it. I did for call on phone using phonestatelistener and InCallSericeAPi, please help me out . Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know about Normal phone calls which can be detected using incallservice apis but i don't have any idea about whatsapp calls. For calls through phone i think we have to use NotificationListener.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).